# Как сделать рандомный инициализирующий вектор AES?

Tags: java, шифрование, aes

Мне сказали, что вроде бы в идеале инициализирующий вектор должен генерироваться случайно (и я где-то об этом читал вдобавок), но ведь если он будет каждый раз генерироваться случайно, то и дешифровываться данные будут неправильно, так ведь? Что имелось в виду, чего я не понял? Вот мой код шифровки и дешифровки

```
public class AesCipher {

    private static final String INIT_VECTOR = "ItIsOurBigSecret";

    // зашифрование
    static byte[] encrypt(byte[] secretKey, byte[] plainText, String mode) {

        try {
            if (!isKeyLengthValid(secretKey)) {
                throw new Exception("Длина ключа должна быть 128, 192 или 256 бит!");
            }

            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(INIT_VECTOR.getBytes());
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/" + mode + "/PKCS5Padding");
            if (mode.equals("ECB"))
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            else
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

            return cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        } catch (Throwable cause) {
            System.out.print(cause.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }


    // дешифрование
    static byte[] decrypt(byte[] secretKey, byte[] cipherText, String mode) {

        try {
            if (!isKeyLengthValid(secretKey)) {
                throw new Exception("Длина ключа должна быть 128, 192 или 256 бит!");
            }

            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(INIT_VECTOR.getBytes());
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/" + mode + "/NoPadding");
            if (mode.equals("ECB"))
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            else
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

            return cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        } catch (Throwable cause) {
            System.out.print(cause.getMessage());
            Controller.ShowMessage(cause.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }


    // проверка длины ключа
    private static boolean isKeyLengthValid(byte[] key) {
        return key.length == 16 || key.length == 24 || key.length == 32;
    }


    // генерация инициализирующего вектора
    private static String genInitVector() {

        Random r = new Random();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            char code = (char) (r.nextInt(94) + 33); // символы с кодами от 33 по 126
            builder.append(Character.toString(code));
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно IV передают вместе с зашифрованным сообщением (реже вычисляют на основе каких-то данных). Можно вставлять 16 байт IV вначале перед зашифрованными данными. На безопасность это никак не влияет.

Снегерировать правильный IV можно при помощи `SecureRandom`:

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
```

Comment: А IV вставлять также зашифрованным или просто вставить `ivParameterSpec`?

Comment: @СергейГуков вы не сможете так просто зашифровать IV. Просто вставляйте массив 16 байт вначале перед зашифрованными данными. Функция encrypt будет возвращать на 16 байт больше чем обычно. Функция decrypt будет вырезать IV из начала массива, и дальше дешифровать.

Comment: Извините, а куда вставить? Сюда `return cipher.doFinal(plainText);`? Объединить два массива таким образом `return ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[iv.length + cipher.doFinal(plainText).length]).put(iv).put(cipher.doFinal(plainText)).array();`?

Comment: @СергейГуков нельзя вызывать `doFinal` 2 раза. Запишите результат в локальную переменную, а потом объединяйте вашим способом.

Comment: Не подскажите, что не так? https://pastebin.com/hXbTjKWL

Comment: @СергейГуков вы передаете весь ciphertext в doFinal при дешифровке. Нужно обрезать первые 16 байт

Comment: Вроде бы сделал все правильно, но расшифровывает весь текст неправильно. Если не трудно, подскажите в чем дело? https://pastebin.com/raGay9gR

Comment: @СергейГуков ну я не буду за вас каждую мелкую ошибку исправлять. зачем вы копируете с 15 байта, если нужно с 16?